# Hadoop on Windows - install without internet connection

Tags: windows, hadoop

I’m trying to install Hadoop on Windows (7), on the stand-alone machine without internet connection. All relevant tutorials I've found on the web relate to Linux and other OS's, but not to Windows. Can you suggest a tutorial for Hadoop installation on Windows, stand-alone computer without internet connection?